# Determine state of viewcontroller in storyboard

Tags: ios6, storyboard, viewcontroller, evernote

I'd like to know how to manage this:

I have 4 viewcontrollers in a storyboard, each one has the same class but i would like to know how to determine when they change their state from fullscreen to invisible and viceversa. any hints?. BTW i have a main view that works like evernote with multiple tabs, and i can already switch between them but i want to put different return buttons on each view, don't know where to begin.

Comment: What do you mean with invisible? Are their views still on screen, but with the view's "hidden" property set to YES or what?

Comment: not exactly invisible the views are contained in other view so when i says they are invisible i mean that i have translated their position, it's like evernote with their notes tabs (premium, location, notepads, etc)

Answer (score 0):

You can find out the size of the window with `self.view.window.bounds` and test it against the frame of your ViewControllers' view with:

```
CGRectContainsRect(self.view.window.frame, myViewController.view.frame)
```

This will return true if the view is on screen and false otherwise.

Comment: ok but is there a method like viewDidLoad or initWithCoder, etc that manage any change in the state of the viewcontroller??

Comment: There are plenty of them, like viewDidLoad, viewWillAppear, etc., however i'll need some more specific details about your implementation in order to help you, such as: do you initialise all of your view controllers in a parent view controller? How do you transition from one view controller to another? Your question is a bit too vague!

Comment: i've started with kieran laferty note viewcontroller to learn about interfacing but when i wanted every noteview to display different controllers, classes and views i couldn't make them check when they resized. BTW i'm a total noob on iOS that's why i tried to learn from that source